# How to track the completion of a function and add a click event handler?

Tags: javascript

How can I make the click event handler speed up the type function and then replace the text with the desired one?

> Each type () function runs on scrolling if the block comes into view

### My code

https://jsfiddle.net/sp_true/b5rj8mvd/4/

```
 function typeCode(lineItem) {
    const codeLine = lineItem.querySelector(".type"),
      columnBlock = lineItem.querySelector(".column"),
      code = codeLine.innerHTML,
      lengthContent = lineItem.querySelector(".hide-text").innerHTML.split('br').length

    let str = code,
      i = 0,
      isTag,
      text;
    columnBlock.innerHTML = Array(lengthContent + 1).fill(0).map((_, i) => `<span>${i+1}</span>`).join('<br>');

    (function type() {
      text = str.slice(0, ++i);
      if (text === str) return;

      lineItem.querySelector('.type').innerHTML = text;
      let char = text.slice(-1);
      if (char === '<') isTag = true;
      if (char === '>') isTag = false;

      if (isTag) return type();
      setTimeout(type, 40); // Here is speed to All Block left anim (60)
    }());
  }
```

Comment: look for  `debounce` function it will help you in this case

Comment: what to look for is understandable, but to rewrite the function for this here causes difficulties in execution (

Comment: You should check this - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/